# Getting EigenVector to be same [[1]] for set of images after computing PCA for GrayScale image

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, pca

I am trying to get unique features (single unique value) of each single image present in the folder.
For which using PCA to get mean,eigenvalue,eigenvector for each single present in the folder of images.
But as per analysis found eigenvector to be same [[1]] for each single image.
Whereas eigenvalue found to be unique.
 Is this as proper behavior ?

Code :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

in_matrix = None 
imP = "abc.jpg"
im = cv2.imread(imP, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
h,w = im.shape[:]
vec = im.reshape(w * h)
in_matrix = np.vstack((in_matrix, vec))
mean,eigvec,eigval = cv2.PCACompute2(in_matrix,  np.mean(in_matrix, axis=0).reshape(1,-1))
///Result : [[133.97159]] [[1.]] [[1658.029]]
```

Comment: "trying to get unique features" -- what would those be ? and what is the vstack for ? vec ?

Comment: @berak i am trying to represent each single image as single number which will represent the whole image.

Comment: i dont think, your approach is feasible. all you'll get like this is the "most prominent pixel value", not really representative. maybe "image hashing" (e.g. phash) is what you want